# How to implement a flexible table

Tags: database, postgresql

I am a novice database user (not designer). I would like to implement the following item in the postgres database.

I would like to implement a database which contain the following information

```
Table1
Classroom | Classroom Type | AV System | Student1  | Student2 | ... | Student36
1A        | 'Square'       | 1         | 'Anson'   | 'Antonie'| ... | 'Zalda'
1B        | 'Rectangle'    | 2         | 'Allen'   | 'Andy'   | ... | 'Zeth'
```

There is another table to store the seating plan for each student, that's why I created another table

```
Table2
Classroom Type | Student1 Position | Student2 Position | ... | Student36 Position
'Square'       | (1,1)             | (1,2)             | ... | (6,6)
'Rectangle'    | (1,1)             | (1,2)             | ... | (4,9)

Table3
AV System | TV          | Number of Speaker
1         | 'LCD'       | 2
2         | 'Projector' | 4
```

The reason of this implementation is to draw a seating plan. However I don't think this is a good implementation. Therefore I would like to find another way which will give me some flexibility when I want to scale it up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the prefixed tag from your title. There's no need to add tags, the tag system takes care of that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/147072 for more information.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you can get a grasp of how to design tables at wikipedia, [Entity-relationship model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how relational databases work. In a relational database you don't repeat attributes, you create 1:N relationships. This process is called normalization and one of its main goals is to prevent duplication of data.

As far as I can tell, the following structure would do what you want:

```
-- a table to store all possible classroom  types ("Square", "Rectangle", ...)
create table classroom_type
(
   type_id     integer not null primary key,
   type_name   varchar(20) not null, 
   unique (type_name)
);


-- a table to store all classrooms    
create table classroom
(
   room_id      integer not null primary key,
   room_name    varchar(5) not null, 
   room_type    integer not null references classroom_type,
   unique (room_name)
);

-- a table containing all students
create table student
(
   student_id    integer not null primary key, 
   student_name  varchar(100) not null
   --- ... possibly more attributes like date of birth and others ....
);

-- this table stores the combinations which student has which position in which classroom
create table seating_plan 
(
   student_id   integer not null references student,
   room_id      integer not null references room,
   position     varchar(10) not null,
   primary key (student_id, room_id), -- make sure the same student is seated only once in a room
   unique (room_id, position) -- make sure each position is only used once insid a room
);
```

I used `integer` for the ID columns, but most probably you might want to use `serial` to automatically create unique values for them.

Most probably the model needs to be extended to include a school year as well. Because student Allen might be in room 1A this year, but in 3C next year. This would be another attribute of the `seat_plan` table (and would be part of the primary key)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I add room_name in table student?

Comment: @Winston: No, because a student doesn't "have" a room_name, does he/she? The association between a room and a student is done through the `seating_plan` table.

Comment: But every student is unique - Every student exist in one room.

Comment: @Winston: really? What if the student changes the class? What about next year? The room_name is **not** an attribute of the student. It's an attribute of the room. Students and rooms are two completely different entities with their own set of attributes. They only come "together" within the concept of a seating plan. And then you only need the reference to the room (which in turn has a room name).

Comment: If the student change class (e.g. from 1A to 2B), then I will go to student table and make the corresponding changes. Am I confusing you? BTW thanks for solving my problem.

Comment: @Winston: In your example `1A` is a "classroom" not a class. You apparently failed to mention that you also have classes. In that case my model will need additional entities: an entity "class" and a relation between `student` and `class` - because the class is not an attribute of the student (as that too will change every year)

Answer (score 0):

```
|ClassRoomTypes|      |   ClassRooms   |     |   TableTypes   |    |    Tables  |
|--------------|      |----------------|     |----------------|    |------------|
|Id            |<---  |Id              |     |Id              |<-  |Id          |
|Name          |   |  |Name            |     |Name            | |--|TableType_Id|
|--------------|   ---|ClassRoomType_Id|     |Size_X          |    |------------|
                                             |Size_Y          |
                                             |----------------|

|ClassRoomToTables|       |ClassRoomToTable_Students|     |      Students     |
|-----------------|       |-------------------------|     |-------------------|
|Id               |<---   |Id                       |     |Id                 |
|ClassRoom_Id     |    |--|ClassRoomToTable_Id      | OR  |Name               |
|Table_Id         |       |Student_Id               |     |ClassRoomToTable_Id|
|-----------------|       |-------------------------|     |-------------------|
```

Now a explaination:

A **Class Room** has a list of tables.

A **Table** has some paramenters ( eg: Student Capacity; Size_X, Size_Y etc)

A Table also **it's a concept**, (It's not something unique identificated, a table concept is used in many class rooms)

One or many **students sit at many tables in different** class rooms (ClassRoomToTable_Students table)

```
                                   OR
```

One or many students may sit **only at a table** from specific class room (ClassRoomToTable_Id from Students)

You may get some inspiration from my point of view, I do not guarantee that totally fits your domain case. Success